# Проблема подключением библиотеки pytorch (Python)

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch

Я установил себе на Windows 10 актуальную сборку Anaconda (Python) и при помощи команды
`conda install -c pytorch pytorch` в командной строке Anaconda благополучно установил библиотеку pytorch. 
В качестве среды разработки я использую Jupyter, входящий в состав Anaconda. И при первой же попытке использовать в коде библиотеку pytorch получил ошибку:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-295038481219> in <module>
----> 1 import utils
      2 import torch
      3 import torch.nn as nn
      4 import torch.nn.functional as F
      5 import torch.optim as optim

E:\Mail Cloud\Progs\Jupyter\Temp\01\utils.py in <module>
----> 1 import torch
      2 from torch import utils
      3 from torchvision import datasets, transforms
      4 import matplotlib
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py in <module>
     79     dlls = glob.glob(os.path.join(th_dll_path, '*.dll'))
     80     for dll in dlls:
---> 81         ctypes.CDLL(dll)
     82 
     83 

C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль
```

Предполагаю, что программа не распознаёт путь к какой-то библиотеке или не хватает какого-то файла, но не понятно какого и как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы найдено. Отладка показала, что сбой возникает при попытке загрузить caffe2_nvrtc.dll, которая работает с CUDA. У меня карта AMD, которая CUDA не поддерживает, соответственно драйвер NVidia не стоит, а caffe2_nvrtc.dll без него не работает. Короче, нужно было просто поставить версию torch без поддержки CUDA и всё завелось.